# Laravel has many and grouping

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I can't seem to get the syntax right for this query.

Basically, I have a product that is listed, where an offer is made by a user:

So in `Offer.php`

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'buyer_id');
}
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

And in `User.php`

```
public function offers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer', 'buyer_id');
}
```

Then in `Product.php`

```
public function offer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
}
```

I need to group offers by the user that has made them, and then group that again by the category of the product the offer is against.

Does anyone have ideas where I can start to group these correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure, but are you looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: I think you should follow this link https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/

Answer (score 1):

Try with `Query Builder`. Like this ( I don't know your tables`s structure):

```
 $offers = DB::table('offers')
             ->joinLeft('users','users.id','=','offers.buyer_id')
             ->joinLeft('products','products.id','=','offers.product_id')
             ->groupBY('users.id','products.category_id')
             ->get();
```

Comment: So i've basically amended it a little bit but its it's in raw sql (sorry), but im getting this error: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'bmoty.offers.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by when running: SELECT * FROM offers LEFT JOIN users ON users.id  = offers.buyer_id left join products ON products.id = offers.product_id group by products.category;

Comment: @iLC Sorry, I don't know your tables's structures and your sql-query  => can't say exactly how to write proper sql-query and why you get error . * IMHO, don`t use Eloquent in this case : make it`s via raw sql-query.